# How to count occurrences of a column value and concat it to the same colums in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table of sales

I want to query for all sales, and concatenate ID column that counts how many sales are of the same ID:

The query should display in below format,can you please let me know the efficient way of doing it.

[image: Sales Table]

[image: Table to be displayed after querying]

Comment: `CONCAT(ID, '_', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(ID, '_', 1), Segment) ORDER BY ID)`

Comment: Step 1: Normalise your schema

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  Your results also don't make sense.  Please explain how the values are calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ROW NUMBER` and `CONCAT` function to achieve the Same.

```
SELECT CONCAT(ID, '_', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(ID, '_', 1), Segment) ORDER BY ID) 
FROM Tablename
```